# How to setup a Wild Card 301 redirect that will remove URL parameters on Apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Ok I've seen alot of examples out there but I still can't seem to get it right. I've got old urls from an old e-platform that are indexed in the engines heavily that have non seo-friendly parameters that I need to 301 redirect to my root.

I need to globally 301 redirect anything from /store/ to our root. Here's what I've got thus far.

```
RewriteRule ^store/.*$ / [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

its partially doing the job but it's not removing the parameters. Here's an example of a parameter I am experiencing issues with. `store/index.php?cPath=1`

Hopefully we can fix in place soon because is giving me grief about these urls.

Answer (score 3):

In order to get rid of the query string, which automatically gets appended to the end of mod_alias and mod_rewrite redirects, you need to create your own query string, but make it empty. So you simply want to add a `?` to the end of the redirect/rewrite target. Example:

using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^store/ /? [R=301,L]
```

using mod_alias:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/store/ /?
```

Note that with mod_alias, the `?` will show up in the URL address bar.

Comment: Hi jon, I wanted to thank you for the help on this question. We're now seeing the same issue pop-up but instead with /store/... its with /index.php   example of url: index.php?cPath=1_83   ive tried using the below solution and removed store/ and added index.php but no go. Here's what Ive added to the hta: RewriteRule ^index.php/.*$ /? [R=301,NE,NC,L]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following one:

```
RewriteRule ^store/([^\.]+\.[^?]+) /$1 [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

that will exclude all parameters from the url, so `/store/index.php?cPath=1` will translate to `/index.php`

Comment: I gave it a go and the following happens.  a request for domain.com/store/ displays a 404,  a request for domain.com/store/index.php becomes domain.com/index.php which I can't have for SEO purposes (duplicate home page) and a request for domain.com/store/index.php?cPath=5 becomes domain.com/index.php?cPath=5  so this will not work.

Comment: I need you clarify more what you want, give concrete example of your input urls and the expected output from those.

Comment: oki doki.  I globally want to redirect anything with /store/ path to root domain.com not domain.com/index.php otherwise Google will think I have a duplicate home page. (bad seo) They're already giving me grief about these urls. Here's the deal on the urls with parameters. They all use this format /store/index.php?cPath= and I need everything in the url to redirect to root domain.com. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: let me know if you need more information. sorry I am still a newbie at this.

Comment: so you want: a) store/index.php?cPath=1  -> '/'  or b) store/index.php?cPath=1  -> '/?cPath=1'

Comment: Umm, your original rule should be fine then.. so the problem must be another place, sorry can't help you more. Revise you don't have .htaccess files behind /store overriding your rule.

Comment: really. ok I will take a another look at the hta file. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys!
we got it this time around.

Just as Jon Lin said we were missing a ? somewhere. For anyone that is trying to setup a wild card redirect and has to strip parameters from the url here's our solution.

RewriteRule ^store/.*$ /? [R=301,NE,NC,L]

Cheers!

Comment: You should accept Jon Lin's answer. Only post your own answer if nobody found a solution except you.